# How to generate multiple rows with the key column from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to generate multiple rows for each record in table into another table. This is to generate an excel file for user to key in some data and later import into database.

| State | Branch |
| --- | --- |
| State1 | Branch1 |
| State1 | Branch2 |
| State1 | Branch3 |
| State2 | Branch1 |
| State3 | Branch1 |
| State3 | Branch2 |
| State4 | Branch1 |
| State4 | Branch2 |
| State4 | Branch3 |
| State4 | Branch4 |

Table above will become like this

| State | Branch |
| --- | --- |
| State1 | Branch1 |
| State1 | Branch2 |
| State1 | Branch3 |
| State1 | Branch4 |
| State1 | Branch5 |
| State2 | Branch1 |
| State2 | Branch2 |
| State2 | Branch3 |
| State2 | Branch4 |
| State2 | Branch5 |
| State3 | Branch1 |
| State3 | Branch2 |
| State3 | Branch3 |
| State3 | Branch4 |
| State3 | Branch5 |
| State4 | Branch1 |
| State4 | Branch2 |
| State4 | Branch3 |
| State4 | Branch4 |
| State4 | Branch5 |

Can see that, State1-Branch1 only have 3 records, but I need to generate 5 rows, and same for other branches.
This will then export to excel file and let user to key in the information.
And the end the file will import back to db.

May I know how to generate the table with 5 lines for each branch?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select 'State'||state, 'Branch'||generate_series(1,5)
from generate_series(1,4)as a(state);
```

| ?column? | ?column? |
| --- | --- |
| State1 | Branch1 |
| State1 | Branch2 |
| State1 | Branch3 |
| State1 | Branch4 |
| State1 | Branch5 |
| State2 | Branch1 |
| State2 | Branch2 |
| State2 | Branch3 |
| State2 | Branch4 |
| State2 | Branch5 |
| State3 | Branch1 |
| State3 | Branch2 |
| State3 | Branch3 |
| State3 | Branch4 |
| State3 | Branch5 |
| State4 | Branch1 |
| State4 | Branch2 |
| State4 | Branch3 |
| State4 | Branch4 |
| State4 | Branch5 |

If you only need to generate the `state` labels and `branch`es are listed somewhere:

```sql
select 'State'||state, branch
from generate_series(1,4)as a(state),
     (select distinct branch from branches)b;
```

If you already have tables listing all `state`s as well as all `branch`es you want:

```sql
select state, branch
from (select distinct state  from states)s,
     (select distinct branch from branches)b;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9IQfVGJi)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using `GENERATE_SERIES()` and `CROSS JOIN` :

```
SELECT t.State, 'Branch' || s.Branch AS Branch
FROM generate_series(1, 5) AS s(Branch)
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT State FROM mytable
) as t
ORDER BY t.State
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/dlfoKWam)